# Set free price product by category ID based on user ID

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to set free price product by category ID based on user ID on woocommerce, but it does not working.
Any help is appreciated.

My code so far:

```
function set_free_price_for_category( $price, $product ) {

    $category_ids = array( 123 );
    $target_user_id = 123;
    $user_role = 'customer';
    
    if ( has_term( $category_ids, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) && user_can( get_current_user_id(), $user_role ) && == $target_user_id ) {
        $price = 0;
    }
    
    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'set_free_price_for_category', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some problems on get current user id. So, I have revisited your code nearly completely and managed to fix your issues.

```
/*set free price product by category ID based on user ID*/

function set_free_price_for_category( $price, $product ) {

    $category_ids = array( 123 );
    $target_user_id = 123;
    $user_role = 'customer';
    
    if ( has_term( $category_ids, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) && user_can( get_current_user_id(), $user_role ) && get_current_user_id() == $target_user_id ) {
        $price = 0;
    }
    
    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'set_free_price_for_category', 10, 2 );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). tested and works.